# Strip whitespace from Mako template output (Pylons)

Tags: python, html, pylons, mako

I'm using Mako + Pylons and I've noticed a horrendous amount of whitespace in my HTML output.

How would I go about getting rid of it? Reddit manage to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do it within Mako itself but you can always just do some post-rendering processing before you serve up the page.  For example, say you have the following code that generates your horrendous whitespace:

```
from mako import TemplateLookup

template_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['.'])
template = template_lookup.get_template("index.mako")
whitespace_mess = template.render(somevar="no whitespace here")
return whitespace_mess # Why stop here?
```

You could add in an extra step like so:

```
from mako import TemplateLookup

template_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['.'])
template = template_lookup.get_template("index.mako")
whitespace_mess = template.render(somevar="no whitespace here")
cleaned_up_output = cleanup_whitespace(whitespace_mess)
return cleaned_up_output
```

...where cleanup_whitespace() is some function that does what you want (it could pass it through [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [slimmer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimmer/0.1.29) or whatever).  It isn't the most efficient way to do it but it makes for a quick example :)

Answer (score 8):

There's the backslash thing.

Look at the homepage of mako http://makotemplates.org for an example.

```
<%def name="makerow(row)">
    <tr>
    % for name in row:
        <td>${name}</td>\
    % endfor
    </tr>
</%def>
```

But seriously, I wouldn't spend to much time trying to format correctly the ouput. What is important is to have readable template code. I use the web inspector of Webkit (or FireBug, if you prefer) more often than "view source".

If really you want good formatted html output, you could always write a middleware that does that.

Comment: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html?highlight=empty#newline-filters

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this without post-processing would be to avoid whitespace in the template. However, that will make things very hard for you as a developer.

You need to make a decision about whether the time to clean the HTML string after the template has been rendered will save sufficient bandwidth to offset this cost. I recommend using optimized C code library to do this for you, such as [`lxml.html`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html).

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> page = html.fromstring("""<html>
... 
... <body>yuck, a newline! bandwidth wasted!</body>
... </html>""")
>>> html.tostring(page)
'<html><body>yuck, a newline! bandwidth wasted!</body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Dan's answer, I passed the rendered output through this function which only preserves "deliberate" whitespace. I defined that to be two carrage returns in a row (i.e an empty line)

So

```
Hello 
There
```

Becomes

```
Hello There
```

But

```
Hello

There
```

Becomes

```
Hello
There
```

Here's the code

```
def filter_newline(input):
    rendered_output = []
    for line in input.split("\n"):
        if line:
            # Single new-lines are removed
            rendered_output.append(line)
        else:
            # Subsequent newlines (so no body to the interveaning line) are retained
            rendered_output.append("\n")

    return "".join( rendered_output )
```

Execute like so (I stole part of Dan's example)

```
whitespace_mess = template.render(somevar="Hello \nThere")
cleaned_up_output = filter_newline(whitespace_mess)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data are not too dynamic, you could store an optimised cache of the template output and serve this to web clients.

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to my whitespace problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, have Mako generate the templates as it does now. And, rather than adding the complexity of post-processing each request (most likely via regular expressions), serve a cached version of the page once it has been processed.