# Mako's analog of Django's "spaceless" tag?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

Is there a mechanism in Mako templates that would allow me to remove extra spaces from the template output, similar to Django's `{% spaceless %}` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868722/strip-whitespace-from-mako-template-output-pylons), but basically it doesn't look like it's supported under Mako directly.

I do want to point out, however that Jinja2 does support whitespace removal via the {%- and -%} opening and closing tags. It is very easy to use under Pyramid via:

```
pip install pyramid_jinja2

config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
```

From that point forward you can just use the .jinja2 file extension and build your templates.

Anyway, sorry I couldn't give you better news!